# how to get similar traning data for a test sample?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, explainable-ai

- I want to get the most similar samples for test sample on which the model choose it's - output.
- SHAP isn't useful because it show the contribution of each feature.
- I want to get the most similar samples (from the training set), which the model used to predict it's output on a sample test

Comment: Have a look at [the following paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03888.pdf), which uses SHAP values to find samples that are similar based on the model (found as an answer on [this stats stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358130/finding-most-similar-training-samples-for-a-given-ml-model-output).